# Can anyone help explain this solution to determining a graph is non planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Im a bit confused about the solution to this,

It shows a graph, and then explains why the graph is not planar, by showing a $K_{3,3} minor $[image]

[image]

So can anyone help explain what is going on in this picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each blue ellipse is a "left vertex" of $K_{3,3}$ and each green ellipse is a "right vertex" of the same graph.  The edges covered by the ellipses are contracted to give the minor and the top vertex of the star is simply omitted.

Comment: And you can simply just delete any vertex when looking for a minor correct?

Comment: Yes, extracting a [graph minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) involved deleting vertices and edges, and contracting some of the other edges.